# How to find location using MapKit in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, mapkit

Hey everyone,
I was wondering how to use the MapKit in Xcode? A lot of people told me not to use the Google Map website and integrate it with the UIWebView because it seems a little strange when people are viewing the location in a web view, so I was wondering if anyone can help me step-by-step how to setup MapKit, how pinpoint an address location on the map and find the routes between user's current location and the pinpointed address location? Sorry if I'm not a really good programmer with MapKit and hope someone can help me, thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
youruimapview.showsUserLocation=TRUE;
```

Comment: To improve the quality of your post, please explain how/why this will solve the OP's problem.