# MKMapView - how to see location by pkace enterd

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit

i want to know if i can see place on map-MKMapView- by entering the name of a place.
like if i enter "Paradise Valley, AZ, United States" in here http://maps.google.com/ and it give me the location on the map of that place.

Comment: The short answer to your question would be "yes". But that's not really what your are asking for is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is source code of  **Address to Coordinate** and  **ReverseGeoCoordinate**.

http://xxki.com/tutorial/pukiwiki.php?MacOS%2FiPhone%20-%20MapKit

Some more links to MapKit tutorial to learn abt the Map framework in iPhone

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/getting-your-location-in-an-iphone-application

[How to find location using MapKit in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326690/how-to-find-location-using-mapkit-in-xcode)

Answer (score 0):

Forward geocoding is not available in the iOS SDK (unlike reverse geocoding). I use this solution -

http://blog.sallarp.com/ipad-iphone-forward-geocoding-api-google/

This works really well for me. You can try it if you download my app, [iGoBy](http://bit.ly/igoby-app), then go to the map and search for an address (Not trying to advertise here, just to let you see it working :))

Answer (score 0):

Google have this feature available through their [map API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html).

You could also use [geonames.org](http://geonames.org) which have a similar API. My [ILGeoNames](http://github.com/InfiniteLoopDK/ILGeoNames) project on GitHub provides some simple Objective C wrappers for accessing geonames.org.

**Update:**
You would need to do the annotations on the map yourself though.