# Loading current geolocation on UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, geolocation, mapkit

Is there a way where I can get the current geographic location of the user (In my case, Bengluru, India), so that I can call Google Static Map API and load the static map image on the UIWebView of the ViewController.xib

For example,
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-OBTAINED_LOCATION-&zoom=14&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false

Here OBTAINED_LOCATION should be the one that indicates current geographic location of the user.

Comment: I guess you will find your answer here: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326690/how-to-find-location-using-mapkit-in-xcode>

Comment: It shows step by step instructions for MapKit and not UIWebView.. Thanks for the link, I'll keep it bookmarked in case I switch to MapKit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User Following Code:

First access following delegates to your interface:

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
@interface StoresMapView : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>{
CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}
```

Then In **.m** use Following

## Edit:

```
-(void)setMapCenter:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)location
{
NSLog(@"Current Location : %f, %f",location.latitude,location.longitude);
MKCoordinateRegion region;
MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta=0.01;
span.longitudeDelta=0.01;
region.span=span;
//location.latitude=(float *)(self.appDelegate.currentLocationLatitude);
//location.latitude=self.appDelegate.currentLocationLongitude;
region.center=location;
[self._mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
[self._mapView regionThatFits:region];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Location Manager functions

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{   
NSLog(@"Inside Location Delegate = %@", newLocation.coordinate);    

[self._mapView selectAnnotation:[[self._mapView annotations] lastObject] animated:YES];
    [self setMapCenter:newLocation.coordinate];//Call this Metod defined above

[self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];//Don't use this line if u want continous updation in user's location
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"ERROR");
}
```

Comment: this code return user's current location. you will have to add mapview on ur own through code. (what actually you want?)

Comment: I have a .xib in which UIWebView component is there. In the viewdidload method, I have to load the current location of the user inside this UIWebView.

Comment: why are you using webview instead of UIMApView? any way in case of mapview check the edit, to set focus on current location.

Comment: It's an organizational requirement :) So I have to use UIWebView :-)

Comment: Well then I can only help you till You retrieve the cureent location of user. :)

Comment: Can you upload this source code somewhere, say 4shared or mediafire? I am not able to get this working :-(

Comment: Sorry i missed one thing, You also need to add MapKit.framework to your project. do this this will help for sure now. :) and also import two classes (i've added before interface)

Comment: In fact i'll suggest you go through the answer once again as i have added some more line to to it.